# wildfly8 remove (exclude) hibernate4 and use older version

Tags: hibernate, upgrade, wildfly-8

I am upgrading from JBoss 6 to WildFly8. My application uses Hibernate 3.6, but WildFly 8 is bound with Hibernate 4. I do not want to change my version of Hibernate to 4. How can I tell WildFly8 to use another version of Hibernate in my case. I have tried to exclude org.hibernate module, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by setting in persistence.xml:

```
<properties>
    <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:3" />
</properties>
```

and putting in Wildfly org.hibernate.3

```
<resources>
    <resource-root path="jipijapa-hibernate3-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="hibernate3-core.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="hibernate3-commons-annotations.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="hibernate3-entitymanager.jar"/>
</resources>
```

and of course I have copied files there.